# I was learning Django from the Official Documentation but I am Getting the following error in Admin Interface

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

[This is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLxT.jpg)

When I am Clicking on one of the views or table of my database in the admin panel(which is in this case Album)instead of the name of the album I am getting "Album object"written. What probably I have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`ModelAdmin.list_display` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If you don’t set `list_display`, the admin site will display a single column that displays the `__str__()` (`__unicode__()` on Python 2) representation of each object.

You need to add [`__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str) method to your model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```